# Compiling 32bit with 64bit g++ Fedora

Tags: compilation, g++, 32bit-64bit, fedora

When I try to compile my code:

```
g++ -m32 code.cpp
```

I get an error:

> /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.2.1/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
>   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I have installed:

> gcc-6.2.1-2.fc24.x86_64
>
> gcc-c++-6.2.1-2.fc24.x86_64
>
> glibc-devel-2.23.1-10.fc24.i686
>
> libstdc++-devel-6.2.1-2.fc24.x86_64

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

The solution for me was:

```
sudo dnf install libstdc++-static libstdc++-static.i686
```

But you might also need

```
sudo dnf install libstdc++-devel libstdc++-devel.i686
```